# DatePickerDialog resets the date in Android

Tags: java, android, date, datepicker

I am using `datePickerDialog` in my application. I have set **current date** and `onClickListener` both on a same `textView`

Initially textView displays current date and when it listens click event, it shows a `DatePickerDialog`

**What is my problem?**

When I tap on `textView` it shows me `DatePicker` with **current date**, then I set any date, new date is now visible on textView **but** every time I tap on textView it shows **current date** in `datePickerDialog`, I want the `datepicker` to **update** the date on `datePickerDialog` also.

Here is my `Activity.java` snippet

```
final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

//format of the current date
String currDate = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy").format(new Date());

//set current date on textView
dateView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.date_view);
dateView.setText(currDate);

dateView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        DatePickerDialog dpd = new DatePickerDialog(TRTimeReminder.this,
                new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
                        c.set(year, month, day);
                        String date = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy").format(c.getTime());
                        dateView.setText(date);
                    }
                }, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
            dpd.show();
        }
    });
```

## Edit

I also updated `DatePickerDialog(TRTimeReminder.this,.....,mYear, mMonth, mDay)` to `DatePickerDialog(TRTimeReminder.this,....., y, m, d)`

where `int y, m, d` are variables I defined inside `onDateSet()` method as `y = year, m = month, d = day` but when I tap textView it shows initialized date **JAN 1 1900**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are initializing `dpd` with `mYear, mMonth, mDay` as far as I can see you never update those.

Update in regard to comment:

Pulling the data from `Calendar c` when you initialize the new `DatePickerDialog` instead of using stored values.

```
DatePickerDialog dpd = new DatePickerDialog(TRTimeReminder.this,
  new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
        @Override
        Public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
        c.set(year, month, day);
        String date = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy").format(c.getTime());
        dateView.setText(date);
        }

        c.get(Calender.YEAR); // I forgot if you need the ; here when using Java
        c.get(Calender.MONTH;
        c.get(Calender.DAY_OF_MONTH);
});
```

Comment: I also tried changing it. I took `int y, m, d` and defined the variables inside `onDateSet` i.e. `y = year` `m = month` `d = date` and then put `y, m, d` instead of `mYear, mMonth, mDay`. But when I tap on `textView` to pick a date, it initializes the date to **JAN 1 1900**

Comment: Not sure I understand the change you describe. As far as I can see your problem is you take the date out of the Calender c, and store it, when you update the date in c you never change those stored values, and then when you open a new DatePickerDialog you use the old value. Why not initialize with c.get(Calendar.YEAR); instead of mYear?

Comment: would you please explain in your answer

Answer (score 1):

I don't think your code is optimized or correct for several reasons :

1. Each click event you have new instance of Date Picker.
2. I don't think you are even dismissing the previous date picker, even then this code is seriously in bad shape.
3. After setting current date, you are never re-initializing member variables mYear, mMonth, mDay with new values.

Fix your code  -

```
DatePickerDialog dpd = new DatePickerDialog(TRTimeReminder.this,
  new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
        @Override
        Public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
            mYear = year;
            mMonth = month;
            mDay = day;
           // Perform your operation
        }

}, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
```

As per my suggestion, I would prefer implementing below code:-

```
public class CustomDatePicker extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

    private static final String CUSTOM_DIALOG_TAG="custom_dialog";

    public static void showDialog(FragmentManager fm){
        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        CustomDatePicker mPrveInstance = (CustomDatePicker)fm.findFragmentByTag(CUSTOM_DIALOG_TAG);
        if (mPrveInstance != null) {
            ft.remove(mPrveInstance);
        }
        ft.addToBackStack(null);
        // Create and show the dialog.
        CustomDatePicker datePicker = new CustomDatePicker();
        datePicker.show(ft, CUSTOM_DIALOG_TAG);
    }
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
        return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
        // Create Interface and send callback to activity to call show
        // Avoid exposing dialog fragment instance to activity
        Calendar.getInstance().set(year, month, day);
    }

}
```

From Activity directly call show method whenever you want to show it.

```
// CustomDatePicker.showDialog(getFragmentManager());
```

Comment: I'm not using any `FragmentManager`

Comment: It's your choice to not use fragment manager, but I preferred it that way. I have already explained if you want to use don't create several instances on every click callback.

Answer (score 0):

OnDateSet is called after the user has set the date. If you want to show the previous date in the dialog you must first call onCreateDialog and set the date. See code example below:

```
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
int year = 0;
int month = 0;
int day = 0;

// get previous date if available
String dateFormatted = dateView.getText();
Log.i(TAG, "What is the user's date " + dateFormatted);

if (dateFormatted == null || dateFormatted.isEmpty())
{
  // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
  final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
  year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
  Log.i(TAG, "what is the phone's year: " + year);
  month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
  Log.i(TAG, "what is the phone's month: " + month);
  day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
  Log.i(TAG, "what is the phone's day: " + day);
} else
{
  day = Integer.parseInt(dateFormatted.substring(0, 2));
  Log.i(TAG, "what is the user's day: " + day);
  month = Integer.parseInt(dateFormatted.substring(3, 5));
  // Correct month to 0-11 format from 1-12 format
  month = month - 1;
  Log.i(TAG, "what is the user's month: " + month);
  year = Integer.parseInt(dateFormatted.substring(6, 10));
  Log.i(TAG, "what is the user's year: " + year);
}

// Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
}
```

N.B. I am using a DialogFragment which implements  DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener. As such, you may need to change the getActivity to this. I presume it will otherwise work.

Then use onDateSet:

```
public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day)
{
// Do something with the date chosen by the user
Time time = new Time();
time.set(day, month, year);
String date = time.format("%d-%m-%Y");
Log.i(TAG, "The date you are setting: " + date);
dateView.setText(date);
Log.i(TAG, "You have set the date to: " + date);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To reset date picker on cancel click :

1. Add onDismissListner on date picker
2. Inside onDismissListener, call updateData method

Example :

```
datePicker.setOnDismissListener((dialog) -> {
    datePicker.updateData(Year, Month, Date);
}
```

**Note :** You may be thinking that is user clicks Ok this code will give problem. Ideally No. As you are calling updateData in onDateSet then you won't get any problem.

**Reference :** https://stackoverflow.com/a/57703547/1994950